# Find out current user name in golang server that uses Auth0

Tags: rest, go, auth0

I am using `auth0` and `golang` for a rest service that is similar implemented as shown [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/auth0-golang-jwt/blob/master/main.go).

I wonder how I can find out the name of the user that is currently triggering a certain API call - for instance if someone requests `http://localhost:3000/products` - the go handler in this case looks like this:

```
var ProductsHandler = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    payload, _ := json.Marshal(products)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte(payload))
})
```

Does the request `r` contain more information about the current user?

Or do I need to find out the current user in the middleware authentication:

```
func authMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        secret := []byte("{YOUR-AUTH0-API-SECRET}")
        secretProvider := auth0.NewKeyProvider(secret)
        audience := "{YOUR-AUTH0-API-AUDIENCE}"

        configuration := auth0.NewConfiguration(secretProvider, audience, "https://{YOUR-AUTH0-DOMAIN}.auth0.com/", jose.HS256)
        validator := auth0.NewValidator(configuration)

        token, err := validator.ValidateRequest(r)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            fmt.Println("Token is not valid:", token)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            w.Write([]byte("Unauthorized"))
        } else {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    })
}
```

Does the `token` contain more information about the user?

I am a bit lost here. `auth0` works perfectly to ensure that only registered persons can use the REST-API, but I want to deliver user specific information. So it depends on the current user what a REST call is handing back. Initially, I was thinking that auth0 would take care of this. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know much about auth0 specifically, but their quickstart uses totally different libraries - where are you getting the `auth0` package? Try reading the documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `token` to get information about request issue.

To sort all you want you need to take a look to next:

- Check out how token extracted in this method: [token extraction](https://github.com/square/go-jose/blob/v2.1.2/jwt/claims.go#L27)
- And the `Claims` here: [Claims structure](https://github.com/square/go-jose/blob/v2.1.2/jwt/claims.go#L27)
- And how combine it here: [retrieve Claims](https://github.com/auth0-community/go-auth0/blob/64f427eaa850dfad1df4050b1b7ed5270d81338b/auth0.go#L80)

The claims have a field

```
Issuer string `json:"iss,omitempty"`
```

you are interested in.